# Trying to get the path for a file in the assets or raw directory

Tags: android, assets

```
Android Studio 0.8.1
```

Hello,

I have created a keystore called `snapzkeystore.bks` using the `keytool`. I want to get the path so I can pass it to a function and load it. However, I can’t seem to get the path. I have also tried putting it in the raw and assets folder and trying to get it that way and testing what works, However, I also get a `FileNotFoundException` calling this function `keyStoreFile.load(fileInputStream, password)` (code below)

Trying to get it when put in the raw folder Test 1:

```
String uri = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.snapzkeystore;
snapClient.makeRequest(uri.toString());
```

I get FileNotFoundException Exception and the and the string contains:

```
android.resource://com.sunsystem.snapzui/2131034112
```

I have also tried using the assets folder and using this instead Test 2:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
InputStream inputStream;
try {
    inputStream = resources.getAssets().open("snapzkeystore.bks");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(buffer);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer);
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "asset: " + inputStream.toString());
    snapClient.makeRequest(inputStream.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

I get FileNotFoundException Exception and the and the string contains:

```
android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@5363f738
```

Source snippet for loading the keystore:

```
public int makeRequest(String keyStoreFileName) {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStoreFile = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()); 
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFileName);
        // FileNotFoundException
        keyStoreFile.load(fileInputStream, password);
```

Just a quick questions, which is the best folder to put a keystore in, `raw` or `assets`?

[image]

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the path so I can pass it to a function and load it. However, I can’t seem to get the path

That is because there is no path. Those are not files. They are entries in the APK file.

> I get FileNotFoundException Exception and the and the string contains: `android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@5363f738`

That is because you called `toString()` on an `InputStream` returned from the `AssetManager`.

> Source snippet for loading the keystore

`load()` takes an `InputStream`. You do not have to use a `FileInputStream`. You are welcome to pass the `InputStream` that you get from the `AssetManager` to `load()`:

```
KeyStore keyStoreFile = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStoreFile.load(resources.getAssets().open("snapzkeystore.bks"), password);
```

> Just a quick questions, which is the best folder to put a keystore in, raw or assets?

Either should be fine. You can use `openRawResource()` on `Resources`, IIRC, to get an `InputStream` on a raw resource.